# How can we integrate a customer's serverless application with own user base with our OAuth server?

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, integration

We have a simple setup: An authorization server based on OAuth 2.0, which currently only supports the client_credentials grant type. Then we have an API, the resource server, which is protected by requiring an access token from our OAuth server.

All use-cases for our API so far, have been pure machine-to-machine communcation, where it's simply our customers servers running batch jobs.

Today I had a meeting with a new customer. They have an SPA that seemingly does not have its own backend server. It uses AWS for authenticating, and seems to return a JWT, but from what I can tell, they make a lot of API calls directly to publicly available services, and then the logic is all performed in the SPA.

We ideally would've liked them to simply register a single OAuth client with us, so that when users make a request that needs one of our APIs, the request is first routed to their server, which performs the lookup, and then uses their client's credentials to contact our server. But they would prefer to not have to set up a backend. In this case I'm kind of at a loss for how we sensibly let them integrate with our system. They would prefer to send their user's JWT to our system, but I don't think they understand that we would need their key to verify the user's signature in that case, and we don't want to have to create new APIs simply for this purpose.

Would very much appreciate any advice on this issue - thanks very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We ideally would've liked them to simply register a single OAuth
>   client with us, so that when users make a request that needs one of
>   our APIs, the request is first routed to their server, which performs
>   the lookup, and then uses their client's credentials to contact our
>   server.

Your recommended approach is the right way of doing it with Client Credentials Grant.

> They would prefer to send their user's JWT to our system, but I don't
>   think they understand that we would need their key to verify the
>   user's signature in that case, and we don't want to have to create new
>   APIs simply for this purpose.

If the previous approach doesn't work, I'm afraid that this is the only way of doing it. You will need to implement a Proxy to validate the JWT (You should be able to get their public key to verify the signature). You can do this in AWS itself, using AWS API Gateway + Lambda to verify the JWT to and forward the request to your existing backend with Client Credentials Grant where you don't need to pay anything upfront.

Comment: Hi Ashan, thanks for the answer. That's exactly the solution I suggested too, which just seems like asking for trouble. :( But I guess we'll bow to their needs. I can't imagine their app lives for long, before they start needing a backend.